# Ubuntu 18.04 Terminal shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T is not working

Tags: shortcut-keys

Terminal shortcut-key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
It's normally saved. But when i push shortcut it doesn't run terminal.

How to fix?

Comment: I had the same problem, also on Ubuntu 18.04. Problem started to occur after python3 upgrade from version 3.6.8 to 3.7.3. I found help under this topic (downgrade to previous python3 version): https://askubuntu.com/questions/919908/ubuntu-16-04-a-problem-occurred-when-checking-for-the-updates

Comment: @karel that command forced me to log out ("system encountered a problem it cannot recover from" or similar), and upon logging back in, my terminal won't open at all. Context: I removed a python version that broke my gnome and put things in bad shape in many respects, including disabling the Ctrl+Alt+T command, which is why I'm here. How can I undo that `setsid` command so I can get my terminal back?

Comment: @ggorlen [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/q/384033/)

Comment: @karel I'd used that answer to get my system back (thanks!) and the terminal shortcut was the one (?) last problem (there were probably other issues I hadn't discovered, but things were generally operable). I can redo all of those steps, but will that bring my terminal back and undo the `setsid` command or is there an easier way to simply undo that last command?

Comment: `setsid` doesn't do anything permanent. It doesn't even close any open windows or browser tabs. It also doesn't log out from the current desktop session. `setsid gnome-shell --replace` only refreshes gnome shell.

Comment: I seem to have fixed both the terminal and Ctrl+Alt+T problems with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1239610/853475), downgrading to 3.10 from 3.11. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to add the shortcut manually.

However, the first thing we'll do before adding the shortcut manually is to see if it's there, and if a reset would fix it.

First, go into the Settings.

Second, go to devices, then go to keyboard. Then see if the shortcut is on there. Hit "reset all" and see if it brings it back. Maybe reopen the settings just in case to see if the shortcut comes back. If that fails then do the manual solution:

1. Return to the keyboard settings.
2. Go all the way to the bottom of the list where a "+" button exists. Click on it.
3. After that, give it a name (like "open terminal") and a command, which will be "gnome-terminal"
4. Then after that, click on the "set shortcut" button, and enter in your hotkey shortcut. Exit out and you're done.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: On Ubuntu Mate enter command: "mate-terminal"  instead of suggested "gnome-terminal"

Answer (score 6):

For those of you who have the same problem and the answer here doesn't work either, it might be related to your python upgrade. I changed from python 3.6 to 3.7 and my terminal icon and its shortcut stopped working. I tried many solutions but the only thing that worked was to go back to python 3.6. You can do it this way: right-click on a point in desktop and choose "open terminal". Then type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

and choose a version of python3 that is lower than 3.7. If right-click did not work for you, you can either try the terminal from VSCode or XTerminal (you can download it by just searching it).

Comment: After trying a lot of solutions, this finally worked for me Ubuntu 18.04! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I thought <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is not working. But a while ago, I found that it indeed working, when I use the left alt key. It took so long for me to realize the problem was with the right  <kbd>alt</kbd>  key, as I never tried this key combination with the left  <kbd>alt</kbd>  key.

To get the left  <kbd>alt</kbd> key back to working condition I did the following.

- Open "Tweaks" (aka "Gnome Tweaks") go to "Keyboard & Mouse" ->
  "Additional Layout Options" -> "Key to choose the 3rd level" and put
  a checkmark on "**Right Alt never chooses 3rd level**".

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem intermittently and the accepted answer has solved it in the past, but not when I tried today! Another solution I've found, which is kind of the opposite of what is suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1143550/353863), is the following:

- install compizconfig-settings-manager: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
- run `ccsm`
- in the "General" settings click on "Commands"
- tick the plugins check box to "Enable Commands"
- in the "Commands" tab enter /usr/bin/gnome-terminal into the "Command line 0" box
- in the "Key Bindings" tab click the button "Disabled" on the "Run Command 0" line and click to the "Grab key combination" button to capture the Ctrl+Alt+T command (or edit it manually and type "t") - this may warn you that it's conflicting with the Gnome settings, but seeing as that's not working anyway...!

Use Ctrl+Alt+T and check that it works!

Answer (score 0):

I tried [Matt Pitkin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258913/749186) and it was even easier than that, all I had to do is uncheck and check the "Enable Commands" tickbox and the commands started working again. I did not need to add any new Key Binding.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the ways mentioned in all the answers. Nothing did work for me. It's happening since I installed an app called 'terminator', I uninstalled it, and ola, and it's working.

Maybe one should try uninstalling any package/app whose installation might have caused the key combination to stop working.